# Create correct JSON class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I created a class for a json object (not automatically).
However, I don't quite understand how to make the button object contain nameless arrays as in the example?

**Example JSON** (what the server expects to receive):

```
 {
       "one_time":false,
       "buttons":[
          [
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"location",
                   "payload":"{\"button\": \"1\"}"
                }
             }
          ],
          [
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"open_app",
                   "app_id":6232540,
                   "owner_id":-157525928,
                   "hash":"123",
                   "label":"LiveWidget"
                }
             }
          ],
          [
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"vkpay",
                   "hash":"action=transfer-to-group&group_id=181108510&aid=10"
                }
             }
          ],
          [
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"text",
                   "payload":"{\"button\": \"1\"}",
                   "label":"Red"
                },
                "color":"negative"
             },
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"text",
                   "payload":"{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                   "label":"Green"
                },
                "color":"positive"
             },
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"text",
                   "payload":"{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                   "label":"Blue"
                },
                "color":"primary"
             },
             {
                "action":{
                   "type":"text",
                   "payload":"{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                   "label":"White"
                },
                "color":"secondary"
             }
          ]
       ]
    }
```

**Keyboard.cs** (manually created class)

```
public class Keyboard
{
    public bool one_time { get; set; }
    
    public List<buttons> buttons { get; set; }
   
}
  
public class buttons
{
    public action action { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
public class action
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string payload { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

**I create an object like this:**

```
var Keyboard_obj = new Keyboard()
            {
                one_time = false,
                buttons = new List<buttons>()
                {
                    new buttons()
                    {
                       
                                action = new action()
                                {
                                    type = "test1",
                                label = "class obj",
                                payload = "{\"button\": \"1\"}"
                                },
                                color = "negative"
                            
                    },
                    new buttons()
                    {
                        action = new action()
                                {
                                    type = "test2",
                                label = "class obj",
                                payload = "{\"button\": \"2\"}"
                                },
                                color = "positive"
                    }
                }
            };
```

How can I remake the class so that I get a JSON object like the example above?

Comment: Why do you want a JSON looking like your example? There's a list of lists of buttons...

Comment: The Json is your expected out put but what is the input? Not how you try to create the thing. but really the input the data bfor transphormation

Comment: Btw you declare button as a list (`List<buttons> buttons`). But it's a list list button `public List<List<Button>> Buttons { get; set; }`. Notice the double open braquet in `"buttons":[
          [` <=

Comment: @DragandDrop ty, thats work for me

Answer (score 1):

You should use [JsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=netcore-3.1)

this code will give you a Json object like the example above:

```
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Keyboard_obj );
```

you can also create an object from Json:

```
Keyboard keyboard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Keyboard>(output );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take your JSON and use Visual studio (use paste as special option) or [online tool](https://json2csharp.com/) to generate classes from the provided JSON then following classes will be generated.

Note - `RootBoject.buttons` Is an array or array instead of single collection.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public bool one_time { get; set; }
    public Button[][] buttons { get; set; }
}

public class Button
{
    public Action action { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string payload { get; set; }
    public int app_id { get; set; }
    public int owner_id { get; set; }
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

So with the provided class schema if you use `JsonConvert` to `searialize` the `RootObject` then you will get the required JSON.

Comment: Can you explain how to create object of Rootobject with that class structure?

Comment: @ArtemiZStudio - Follow these steps --- Copy your Json and open Visual studio -> New .cs file -> Go to Edit -> Paste Specail -> Paster Json as classes.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try using dynamic objects

```
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(input);

decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(myObject.Amount);
string Message = myObject.Message;
```